# How can I access the http access logs in Cloudbees

Tags: java, cloudbees

I am using Cloudbees as my PAAS provider and wish to see the access logs as can be viewed in Tomcat. In my apps section I see a tab showing Application Logs and a tab for Access logs which shows nothing.

Is there a way I can turn on these logs?

Answer (score 0):

This was a configuration problem, and has been fixed now